# Linux Distro for Old Macbook Air?

Tags: linux, macintosh

I just found my old Macbook Air from my university year (Mid-2013, Processor Intel Core i5 1.3, 4 GB Ram, 128 Flash Storage) and I want to change the os to a lightweight linux distro

I have a bit of expereince with Ubuntu but I don't know much about any lightweight distro out there. so my question is:

****Which distro would make better use of the hardware and get a good performace?**

**Which distro get regular updates and have good security?****

any help would be appreciated, guys!! Thanks!

Comment: Hi! The "which distro is good" is really too much of a question that invites opinionated answers, and as a matter of fact is impossible to answer "correctly"; this platform has an explicit rule against such questions. That being said, you must not have looked very far. There's Ubuntu variants optimized for lower-end systems.

Comment: sorry about that. that was my first time posting here. I thought people here would be able to point me to me a particular distro that matches the hardware. I had never install a linux on a macbook.

Comment: Absolutely no harm done!

Comment: For what it's worth, [my documentation on installing Ubuntu on my old 2011 MacBook Pro](https://github.com/seamusdemora/seamusdemora.github.io/blob/master/LinuxOnLate2011.md). I use this installation regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Try these [lightweight linux](https://www.techradar.com/news/best-lightweight-linux-distro) They're all for slightly different purposes.